# would it be possible to create a "friends" type of smart contract?

Tags: solidity, mapping

How would a smart contract that can map an address to its own array and have a function to push strings to the array as well as a function that can display what's in the array to mimic an address having "friends" be created? Or would there a better way to do so than what was stated above

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.6;

contract Friends {

    mapping(address => address[]) innerList;
    
    function addFriend(address owner, address friend) public {
      innerList[owner].push(friend);
    }
    
    function getFriends(address owner) public returns(address[] memory){
        return innerList[owner];
    }
}
```